# Visual Studio 2019 MPF 15.0 is missing

Tags: azure-data-lake, visual-studio-2019

VS 2019 Preview 1 is just released but I am getting this **MPF 15.0 error**. This was happened before with VS 2017 and 2015. So, we are not able to update some extensions even if we download from Microsoft marketplace. Do you have any suggestions?

[image: ss from vs 2019]

[image: ss from manual installation attemp]

Answer (score 6):

In short, from [Mads Christensens instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/09/26/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/), as mentioned by @LarsWa:

Edit extension.vsixmanifest in the zip archive `Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Tools.VisualStudio.Extension.vsix`, search for

```
<Dependencies>
  <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="[4.5,)" />
  <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 15.0" Version="[15.0,)" />
</Dependencies>
```

and remove dependency from Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0. `Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Tools.VisualStudio.Extension.vsix` should install correctly.

Answer (score 2):

(Azure Data Lake team here)
The Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio doesn't support Visual Studio 2019 right now. We are actively working on it. Removing the dependencies manually can successfully install the VSIX, but some features may break.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Azure Data Lake team have not yet updated the extension to support Visual Studio version 16, as pr Mads Christensens instructions found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/09/26/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/)

I wrote to them on twitter, about it. https://twitter.com/Larswa/status/1070710559031640064/status/1070710559031640064 – LarsWA 1 min ago

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF then delete it. This dependency is a legacy one that hasn’t been needed since before Visual Studio 2010